# Mysql запрос на проверку совпадений данных в другой таблице

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. Есть 2 таблички:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге нужно вывести на сайт список из последних 10 сообщений в виде:

ID post + заголовок post + иконка, которая просто оповестит, что в сообщении присутствует хотя бы одно изображение (posts.id = images.postid)

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как выполнить запрос и вывести на страницу.

Comment: А почему бы вам не объединить две таблицы? Просто между изображениями ставьте `;`, так будет динамичней. А потом Експлодом рабивать на урлы, считать и выводить куда надо

Comment: В реальном проекте они не должны переплетаться каким либо образом, лишь путем запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто помог взять нужный курс в освоении JOIN'ов...
Решил свою задачу так:

```
          SELECT 
            a.*,
            b.`id` AS hasImg
          FROM `Tab_A` a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN `Tab_B` b 
            ON a.`id` = b.`postid`
          WHERE ...(свои доп. условия)...
          GROUP BY a.`id`
          ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
          LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял то будет примерно так:

```
select * from(
select p.id,p.post,count(i.id) img
from posts p, images i
where p.id = i.postid(+)
group by i.postid
order by p.id
)q where rownum<=10
```

в поле `img` будет цифра сопостовимая с количеством прикрепленных рисунков, соответственно `0` - нет картинок

еще может быть:

```
select * from(
select p.id,p.post,count(i.id) img
from posts p
left join images i on (p.id = i.postid)
group by i.postid
order by p.id
)q where rownum<11
```

Answer (score 1):

возможны несколько вариантов решения этой задачи, одним из них будет использование подзапроса, вторым - соединение таблиц. Могут быть и другие.
В приведенных запросах значение поля `hasImage` имеет значения `1` или `null`.

**Подзапрос:**
Для каждой выбранной строки поста извлекается 1 в случае, если изображения с нужным `post_id` присутствуют в таблице `images`

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, p.post, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 1 
     FROM images AS i 
     WHERE i.post_id = p.id) as hasImage
FROM posts AS p
```

здесь используется диалект MS SQL, так что конструкции `TOP 10`, `TOP 1` следует заменить на `limit 10`, `limit 1`.

**Соединение таблиц**

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.id, p.post, d.hasImage
FROM posts as p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT distinct post_id, 1 as hasImage FROM @images
) as d ON (p.id = d.post_id)
```

Здесь из таблицы изображений выбираются значения идентификаторов постов без повторов. А также значение `1` как флаг, того что изображение есть. В целом можно выбирать просто `post_id` и его же использовать как флаг  наличия.

эти два запроса решают вопрос наличия картинок в принципе. Если же следует знать еще и количество изображений, то необходимо воспользоваться агрегатными функциями, в частности `count`.

С использованием агрегатных функций, так же можно выводить максимальный `id` изображения в качества флага наличия картинок в принципе. В этом случае не придется использовать `LIMIT`  и `DISTINCT` для подзапроса, или склеиваемой таблице.